# Growing patio/dwarf fruit trees to half standard

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, cherries

Is it possible to grow trees larger than their intended (nursery) size?
My mom accidentally bought a 'patio' cherry tree supposedly it will grow to 1.4meter/4,6ft I was wondering if I could try and select a new leader and slowly encourage it to grow taller? Over several years removing the lower branches to start a new crown a bit higher up.
We do not have a problem with limited space or plan to plant it on a patio

Comment: If its a fruiting cherry, having it smaller (in the ground) is very useful, its much easier to pick the cherries, and in my experience, if they are planted in the ground, they get at least 8 feet tall and 6 feet wide. Which variety of tree did she buy?

Comment: Its a prunus avium sylvia (fruiting sweet cherry). I think its grafted on a gisela5 or colt. The nursery label says it wont grow taller than the above mentioned size.

Comment: The dwarfing nature of the rootstock will mean it will always be smaller - pruning it in a particular way will make no difference, though it may branch  out sooner at the top.  Either return it or just plant it, knowing it may well get a little taller than the seller suggests

Comment: Its the same rootstock they use for half standard trees etc. Meaning potentially it can grow bigger. So I guess the question that remains is wether or not I have to accept the height at which the leader has been cut to now or if its possible to choose a new leader and 'move' the crown up over time. I.E. removing lower limbs  making the main trunk taller.